# can't find the proof for the form of odd perfect numbers

Tags: perfect-numbers

I am currently researching perfect numbers and on the wikipedia page, as well as this paper:

http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/articles/opn-mass-rev-060211.pdf

it states that any odd perfect number N must be of the form:
$$
N=q^{\alpha} p_1^{2e_1} \cdots p_k^{2e_k}, 
$$
where:

- q, p1, ..., pk are distinct primes
- q ≡ α ≡ 1 (mod 4)

however I can not find the proof of this anywhere (allegedly proven by Euler), does anybody know it/ can find it?

Comment: Well, at least I haven't seen an odd perfect number *not* of this form yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $N=\prod_k p_k^{m_k}$ with all $p_k$ odd. Then $2N=\sigma(N)=\prod_k(1+p_k+p_k^2+\ldots +p_k^{m_k})$. Note that 
$$1+p+\ldots +p^{m}\equiv\begin{cases}m+1\pmod 4& p\equiv 1\pmod 4\\
0\pmod 4&2\not\mid m,p\equiv-1\pmod 4\\
1\pmod 4&2\mid m,p\equiv-1\pmod 4\end{cases}$$
Since $2N$ is not a multiple of $4$, there must not be any factor that os $\equiv 0\pmod 4$ and exactly one that is $\equiv 2\pmod 2$.
Thus the cases $2\not\mid m$, $p\equiv -1\pmod 4$ and $m\equiv 3\pmod 4, p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ are forbidden; there must be exactly one case of $m\equiv 1\pmod 4$, $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$. The remaining cases, i.e. $m\equiv 0\pmod 2$, $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $2\mid m$, $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ can occur arbitrarily often.

Comment: Some minor changes for typos: line 2 (not including the cases) change 'os' to is,  line 3: change mod 2 to mod 4 to be in agreement with line 2, last line: change 1 to -1 to agree with the cases outlined.